# undefined method for nil class - sending instance from view to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having trouble sending an instance of a model to the controller from the view.

I have a model named profile and a model named report.

```
      <%= form_for(@reported, url: report_path(@profile), html: {method: "post"})  do |f| %>
          <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs disconnect" type="button" onclick="showReport();">
            <i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Report
          </button>
          <%= text_area :reason, :class => "form-control", :rows => "3", :placeholder => "Reason" %>
          <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs disconnect" type="submit" >
             Submit
          </button>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
```

## controller -- route goes here

```
def report 
  @profile.whatever # error here! the @profile variable is nil! 
  #when I thought I passed it here.
end
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You would need to set `@profile` instance variable in Controller before calling `@profile.whatever`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `@profile` to have a value in your controller, you have to initialize it. Typically this is done by fetching a value from the database.

In your controller method (`report`), you have a `params` hash containing the URL or POST params, and probably the one you want is  `params[:id]`. So therefore, you should initialize your object like so:

```
@profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: Is there still a problem then? If so, can you put your `before_action`'s code in the question too?

Comment: Ah, glad you fixed it. What was the problem?

Comment: needed to add this --   before_action :set_profile, only: [..., :report]